# Parse cloud query returns null result

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have the following cloud function

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()
  var query = new Parse.Query("Verification");
  query.equalTo("objectId", "lHBL87Sg2H");

  query.find({
        success: function(results)  
        {
            response.success(results[0].get("objectId"));
        },
        error: function()  
        {
            response.error("failed");
        }
  });
})
```

I call this cloud function in Objective C with the following code,

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"test"
                   withParameters:nil
                            block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@",result);
                                }
                            }];
```

The result of this call is (null).

The parse log shows the following record

```
I2015-04-20T20:07:29.383Z] v81: Ran cloud function test1 for user zOpfIOyZQ1 with:
Input: {}
Result: undefined
```

I also tried the promise  but the output is still null.

Comment: The response message from Parse mentions `test1` function but in the code you mention function `test` is that a typo or different function? Also what output do you get if you add `console.log(results[0].get("objectId"));` right before the `response.success()`? You might be sending `null` as the response and in that case check if `results` contain any items ...

Comment: This is a typo for posting the question. I used test1 consistently in my code.  The output with the console.log(results[0].get("objectId")) is as follows, Input: {}
  Result: undefined
I2015-04-20T22:37:20.926Z]No Message provided

Comment: Thanks for editing, uraimo

Comment: Now I can get objectId of the results[0] using  (results[0]).id following danh's answer. How can I get other properties?

Comment: I just found out that for the objectId, I have to get it with result.id. But for other properties, I can get with result.get("propertyName"). So the query was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an object given its id, use Query.get() as follows ...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query("Verification");
  query.get("lHBL87Sg2H").then(function(object) {
    var objectId = object.id;
    var someAttribute = object.get("foo");
    response.success({"the id is":objectId, "foo is": someAttribute});
  }, function(error) {
    response.error("error " + error.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: Amazing! It worked. But when I replace object.id with  object.get("objectId") the output is still nil. So how can I get other non-default properties of the class? Thanks.

Comment: Please see edit, if I'm understanding the question correctly,  `.id` works for the id, `.get("column_name")` for the non-default properties.